# Move sent messages to Inbox?

Tags: gmail

On Thunderbird I prefer to store sent messages in "Inbox" rather than "Sent" in order to subject them to the same "delete or archive" workflow as received emails, primarily to enable deleting Emails with large attachments before they accumulate.

A common solution for this is to automatically CC or BCC yourself, but this requires [adding third party extensions](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/auto-cc-bcc-outlook-gmail/) in Gmail, which also raises questions about whether this will actually work for e.g. Emails sent from the mobile app.

Can it be achieved with builtin tools?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While Gmail has no direct "select place to store Sent messages" or "CC yourself" option, the effect can be achieved with filter rules.

This is done by creating a filter for the search term `from:me`, applying the "never send it to spam" option.

[image]

Since it is a workaround, depending on an unexpected side-effect of "Never mark as spam", it might stop working at any time though. The unexpected character is demonstrated e.g. by [Gmail (or Google Apps) sent messages duplicate in the inbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42967/gmail-or-google-apps-sent-messages-duplicate-in-the-inbox), where the opposite problem was discussed -- messages accidentally ending up in the inbox because of a filter that matched sent messages.

The advantage of this solution is that it is applied server-side and thus should work regardless of the device sending the message.

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/gmail-users/c/K4jlYGfitHk/m/4tvpfBL8GncJ

Comment: Filters are only applied to incoming messages so you will need to manually run the rule to get the effect you want.

Comment: @Blindspots Strangely, no. It works for me. But as said, it is probably unintended behavior.

Comment: I can see that, I've been noticing lately similar behavior when I have filters set to TO fields and I am the sender the labeling is applied and the message shows in my inbox. Bears more investigation on my part.